# Find the Matching records between the two tables having CSV format

Tags: oracle, select, subquery

A table column has CSV data and B table has normal rows which will check the matching records in A table CSV column. and display the matched string.

```
A table columnid-'XYZ,ABC,JKL,MNO'.
B table columnid: ABC
                  BHU
                  PQR
                  XYZ
Output: ABC
        XYZ.
```

Comment: where is your attempt?

Answer (score 2):

A simple `inner join` can do the trick :

```
SELECT B.columnid
FROM A
INNER JOIN B On A.columnid like '%' || B.columnid || '%';
```

This is an other way to do it using `connect by level` clause to generates a row for each value from our csv column :

```
with cte as (
  select regexp_substr (
           columnid,
           '[^,]+',
           1,
           level
         ) columnid
  from   A
  connect by level <= length ( columnid ) - length ( replace ( columnid, ',' ) ) + 1
)
select C.columnid
from cte C
inner join B on B.columnid = C.columnid;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/bXX4lXWL)